# Query to Linked Server Ignores Configured Timeout Connection

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, linked-server, connectivity, timeout

I need to know where to set the timeout for a login or a query to a linked server. If the server is down I don't want to waste too much time waiting for a timeout. (Our servers are on the same network with a gigabit connection. All are running SQL Server 2017.)

For example,
`SELECT * FROM SERVER_A.master.sys.databases`

runs instantaneously if the linked server is up. If the linked server is down, e.g. if I stop the SQL Server service on SERVER_A, it takes 21 seconds to timeout with the following message:

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "SERVER_A" returned
> message "Login timeout expired".
>
> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for
> linked server "SERVER_A" returned message "A network-related or
> instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection
> to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if
> instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow
> remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books
> Online.".
>
> Msg 2, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>
> Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2].

`EXEC sp_testlinkedserver SERVER_A` times out in the same 21 seconds with the same message.

I can't figure out where the timeout is set. Here is what I've tried:

- Linked Server Properties for SERVER_A\Advanced, I set the Connection Timeout to 1.
- Linked Server Properties for SERVER_A\Advanced, I set the Query Timeout to 1.
- Local server Properites\Advanced, I set Remote Login Timeout to 1. 
  (Same as `EXEC sp_configure 'remote login timeout', 1`)
- Local server Properites\Connections, I set Remote query timeout to 10.
  (Same as `EXEC sp_configure 'remote query timeout', 10`)
- I looked through all of the settings in sys.configurations and couldn't find any that are anywhere near 21.

Regardless of what settings I change, the timeout still takes 21 seconds and returns the above error message.

What am I missing?

---

**UPDATE:**

I tried setting the linked server connection timeout to 43. After that, it took 63 seconds to timeout. We're getting somewhere! Setting it to 30 or 33 times out in 42 seconds, etc. Something is adding either 12 or 20 seconds to the login timeout.

After more testing, it appears that the timeouts I'm experiencing are in multiples of 21 seconds. It's taking 21, 42 or 63 seconds to timeout. It takes longer as I increase the Connection Timeout past a multiple of 21. e.g. if I set the Connection Timeout to 21, it takes 42. If I set it to 50, it takes 63.

Comment: Could you query [sys.servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-servers-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to check the values for `connect_timeout` and `query_timeout`? Also, did you run a  `RECONFIGURE` after changing the options with the `sp_configure`?

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, Ronaldo. When I query sys.servers, I see the configurations I entered: connect_timeout=1 and query_timeout=1, same as the settings I see in the linked server properties box. Besides those two, I don't see other columns that have an obvious connection to timeouts. Also, I did use RECONFIGURE after sp_configure. I meant to say that in the post.

Comment: Did you try to run the remote query more than once? I had this problem with the first attempt taking a long time to fail as I described in my answer. Also, could you try configuring a high value (`sp_configure 'remote login timeout', 0 ;` and the linked server Connection Timeout 43) to see if it takes longer to throw the timeout error?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve it in two ways:

### Configuring a timeout for the whole server

You should configure the server timeout option ([remote login timeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-remote-login-timeout-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver15)) using `sp_configure`:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'remote login timeout', 1 ;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE ;  
GO
```

### Configuring a timeout for the specified Linked Server

You should configure the Connection Timeout with the value 1 or more:

[image: Linked Server properties]

If you query [sys.servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-servers-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) by now, you should see the specified value for the column `connect_timeout`.

---

I noticed a strange behavior after configuring it. SQL Server seems to try the remote connection longer than the specified connection timeout the first time you try to run a query using a linked server (as if it was insisting to be sure it can't reach the remote server). But the following attempts of running a query it threw the connection error quickly as specified.

Comment: I have my remote server configured exactly as yours, and have set 'remote login timeout' to 1 also, and tried the query twice. Still 21 seconds. HOWEVER, I have a new theory: There are two timeouts involved. Per your comment above, I tried setting the linked server connection timeout to 43. After that, it took 63 seconds to timeout. We're getting somewhere! Setting it to 30 or 33 times out in 42 seconds, etc. Something is adding either 12 or 20 seconds to the login timeout.

Comment: As I noted in the original post, two error messages are generated. The first is "Login timeout expired" The second is "A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred..." I'm guessing that it's the second error that's taking the extra time. Do you know where the timeout is for the second one?

Comment: @Robbie, I also got both error messages and I didn't have to configure any other place besides the two options in my answer. One thing that is not clear to me in your comment: are you configuring the timeout on the destine (remote) server instead of the origin server? Like: you have a linked server from server **A** to **B** and your timeout is configured on server **B**? Because the timeout should be on server **A** as server **A** should decide to stop trying to connect to server **B** after the configured timeout.

Comment: I'm making all of these configurations changes on the source server, Server A, as you say, not the target. I should have made that clear. (I presume that configurations on the target server would be unavailable if that server is down.) After more testing, it appears that the timeouts I'm experiencing are in multiples of 21 seconds. It's taking 21, 42 or 63 seconds to timeout. It takes longer as I increase the Connection Timeout past a multiple of 21. e.g. if I set the Connection Timeout to 21, it takes 42. If I set it to 50, it takes 63. Very curious!

Comment: @Robbie, that was my first thought, but when you said "I have my remote server configured exactly as yours" it made me think you could be configuring the wrong server. What about configuring a linked server on the server **B** to see if that behavior is the same or if it's something with instance **A**, can you try that? About the strange time added, when I configured 1 sec it took 2 or 3 sec to actually time out and throw the error. I believe there's some internal process that takes time to generate the error and print it (just a guess, I couldn't find any docs stating it).

Comment: More good ideas, thank you. I tried testing from Server C to Server B. Same results as Server A to Server B above. Then I tried Server B to Server C. Still the same results. All timeouts appear to be in multiples of 21 seconds. (For these tests,Server remote query timeout = 600, Linked Server properties are Query Timeout = 1 and Connection Timeout varies by test.) I share your guess that there could be some internal process that could add 2 or 3 seconds to any timeout. It's the multiples of 21 seconds on our systems that's a real head-scratcher.

Comment: @Robbie, were you able to achieve a solution? I couldn't think of anything else. If you haven't found a solution yet and it's critical to you, maybe you should consider starting a bounty on your question.

Comment: unfortunately, no. I've had my attention elsewhere. If/when I do find a solution, I'll certainly post it here. Thanks again for all your help.